# Codeigniter: Load Library in a Core Class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to extend the `/system/core/Log.php` library with a couple of functions. One function should send a mail in case of an error via the custom function `sendMail()` which is part of the `Custom_library.php`.

Thus, I created the file `/application/core/MY_Log.php`

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function write_log($level, $msg)
  {
    $result = parent::write_log($level, $msg);

    return $result;
  }
}
```

**The problem:** I'm not able to load the `Custom_library.php`. None of these approaches worked:

```
//approach 1    
$this->load->library('Custom_library');

//approach 2  
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('Custom_library');
```

Error message of the approach 2:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/gp/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:366 Stack trace: #0 /home/gp/public_html/application/core/MY_Log.php(13): get_instance() #1 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php(478): MY_Log->write_log('error', 'Severity: error...') #2 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php(105): log_message('error', 'Severity: error...') #3 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php(662): CI_Exceptions->log_exception('error', 'Exception: Clas...', '/home/gp/public...', 366) #4 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #5 {main} thrown in /home/gp/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 366
```

**The question:** Is it possible to load and utilize a Library in a Core Class?

### UPDATE

I tried the approach via the function `&load_class`.

```
function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $param = NULL)
    {
        static $_classes = array();

        // Does the class exist? If so, we're done...
        if (isset($_classes[$class]))
        {
            return $_classes[$class];
        }

        $name = FALSE;

        // Look for the class first in the local application/libraries folder
        // then in the native system/libraries folder
        foreach (array(APPPATH, BASEPATH) as $path)
        {
            if (file_exists($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php'))
            {
                $name = 'CI_'.$class;

                if (class_exists($name, FALSE) === FALSE)
                {
                    require_once($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php');
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        // Is the request a class extension? If so we load it too
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.$directory.'/'.config_item('subclass_prefix').$class.'.php'))
        {
            $name = config_item('subclass_prefix').$class;

            if (class_exists($name, FALSE) === FALSE)
            {
                require_once(APPPATH.$directory.'/'.$name.'.php');
            }
        }

        // Did we find the class?
        if ($name === FALSE)
        {
            // Note: We use exit() rather than show_error() in order to avoid a
            // self-referencing loop with the Exceptions class
            set_status_header(503);
            echo 'Unable to locate the specified class: '.$class.'.php';
            exit(5); // EXIT_UNK_CLASS
        }

        // Keep track of what we just loaded
        is_loaded($class);

        $_classes[$class] = isset($param)
            ? new $name($param)
            : new $name();
        return $_classes[$class];
    }
```

If I run the function `$CI =& load_class('Custom_library');` it finds the right file but than is looking for the Class with a prefix "CI_" and thus throws and error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Custom_library' not found in /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php:196 Stack trace: #0 /home/gp/public_html/application/core/MY_Log.php(14): load_class('Custom_library') #1 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php(478): MY_Log->write_log('error', 'Severity: error...') #2 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php(105): log_message('error', 'Severity: error...') #3 /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php(662): CI_Exceptions->log_exception('error', 'Exception: Clas...', '/home/gp/public...', 196) #4 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #5 {main} thrown in /home/gp/public_html/system/core/Common.php on line 196
```

Comment: Looking closer at the error message of "approach 2" leads me to ask; Is `Custom_library` a controller i.e. `class Custom_library extends CI_Controller`???

Comment: `Custom_library` is a library stored at `application/libraries` not extending `CI_Controller` but -> `class Custom_library { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `CI_Log` is not going to work if you need to access other libraries. The reason is `CI_Log` is created long before `$CI` is created so no "instance" is available for `&get_instance()` to return.

`$this->load` doesn't work because `$this` is not a controller (`$this` and `$CI` point to the same object) and the class `load` ('CI_Loader') hasn't been created yet either.

There might be more than one way around this. Seems to me the least hacked way is to make your logger class utilize `CI_Log` instead of `extend` it.

**application/libraries/Logger.php**

```
class Logger
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('custom_library');
    }

    public function write_log($level, $msg)
    {
        //do stuff with "custom_library"
         $this->CI->custom_library->some_function();

        //use the built-in logging mechanism, a.k.a. CI_Log
        return log_message($level, $msg);
    }

}
```

Your `logger' will need to be loaded in a Controller the same as any other library.

```
$this->load->library('logger');
```

A usage example might be something like this

```
$this->logger->write_log('error', "This is FUBAR");
```

By the time you call `$this->load->library('logger');` the `log` class has been created and is part of `$CI` (a.k.a. `$this`). So this line

```
    //use the built-in logging mechanism, a.k.a. CI_Log
    return log_message($level, $msg);
```

could be done this way instead

```
    //use the built-in logging mechanism, a.k.a. CI_Log
    return $this->CI->log->write_log($level, $msg);
```

That would be marginally more efficient since all `log_message` does is call `log->write_log` anyway. I don't see any problem doing this instead of using `log_message`.

Interesting question and I learned a bunch by looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I updated my question - not sure if I applied your suggestion the right way.

Comment: See my much revised answer.

Comment: Thank for vital insights about codeigniter which headed me to a workaround. I'll post it in a couple of days.